# Complete list of states, that we can query programmatically from the iDevice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is there a complete list of states, that we can query programmatically from the iDevice, eg. UDID, gps coordinates, phone number etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the UIDevice class : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Comment: Very helpfull thank you, but this is not a full list of what we can get at all, eg. gps etc.

Comment: for the gps coordinates you have to use CoreLocation

Comment: i know, but i need a complete list of all states :)

Comment: I don't think you can find this anywhere... Or create your own class to get all the data you want ;)

Comment: Ok i will create my own list. Thank you.